# I have 2 USB ethernet devices of the same type, one works, the other one does not

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb, ethernet

I have 2 (almost) identical USB ethernet devices - product id and vendor id are identical - that both work fine on my pc, but only one of them works on my mac.

This is the diff of the `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` output:

```
-AX88179A:
+AX88179:

   Product ID: 0x1790
   Vendor ID: 0x0b95  (ASIX Electronics Corporation)
-  Version: 2.00
+  Version: 1.00
   Serial Number: **************
   Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
-  Manufacturer: ASIX
+  Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
   Location ID: 0x01100000 / 1
   Current Available (mA): 500
-  Current Required (mA): 100
   Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

The first time I plugged in each of the devices, the Mac asked me whether I want to enable them, which I agreed to. But only the AX88179A variant worked (which I believe to be the one that I plugged in first), and I cannot get the AX88179 one to work.

I tried to "Add Service..." in the network settings, but the device does not show up there, even though (see diff above), `system_profiler` lists the device when plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As that other device with the same product id and vendor id was already working, this came as a surprise, but installing the drivers from https://www.asix.com.tw/en/product/USBEthernet/Super-Speed_USB_Ethernet/AX88179 did the trick!

Now I can use both devices.